# Expected Value using Integration by Parts with Infinite Upper Bound

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to simplify a larger expression that involves this expression: $\int_c^\infty f(x)xdx$, where $c\geq0$ is a choice variable in an optimization problem and $f(\cdot)$ is a density function that is positive everywhere. In simplifying with integration by parts, I have: $$ [F(x)x]_c^\infty - \int_c^\infty f(x)dx $$ The second term is clearly $1-F(c)$, but my only understanding for the first term is $\infty - F(c)c$, which is clearly wrong. Is there some rule/theorem/lemma that I'm missing here?

Comment: the first term must be $[xf(x)]|_c^{\infty}$, not $[xF(x)]|_c^{\infty}$ and probably $f$ decays exponentially at infinity.

Comment: @GReyes I believe you are wrong.

Comment: @JohnK Yes, I am. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your integration by parts should give you
$$
\int_c^\infty xf(x)\ dx 
= \left[xF(x)\right]_c^\infty - \int_c^\infty F(x)\ dx.
$$
But now $\int_c^\infty F(x)\ dx=\infty$, so you get an indeterminate answer of $\infty - \infty$.

**Edit:** Oh, just use $F(x)-1$ instead of $F(x)$. That is, choose the antiderivative of $f$ that goes to $0$ for $x\to \infty$. Then it will likely be well-behaved.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thank you! It seems, then, that integration by parts is not an option for solving this problem. I guess I'm supposed to solve this problem without using first-order conditions.

Comment: @Danny Oh, I wasn't too sharp yesterday either. See my edit.